# How can I drag a prefab into sceneview and put it into a parent node?

Tags: unity

Currently I'm doing like this

```
foreach (var obj in DragAndDrop.objectReferences)
                {
                    GameObject go = GameObject.Find(obj.name);
                    
                    if (go != null)
                    {

                        GameObject parent = GameObject.Find("Parent");
                        if (parent == null)
                        {
                            parent = new GameObject();
                            parent .name = "Parent";                            
           
                        }
                        go.transform.SetParent(temp.transform);
                    }
                }
```

However, I try to drag something with the same name and it will be instantiated by other name(like A(1) rather than A), I can't find it with its name.

Also I try to create an instance by my own and put it to my parent node by code when I drag something into scene view. However, it seems unity will create an instance by itself so I will have two copies of instance in the scene view.

So how can I get the instantiated objects and put them to my parent node?

Comment: You could craete an empty GameObject Prefab first and use this with Instantiate to set your parent.

Comment: I'm not quite clear about your meaning, could you please show the code?

Comment: [I would advise avoiding looking up objects by name](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/672973048899702784?t=AI_F1IL24c3abFSA-RFbtg&s=19). There is almost always a more reliable distinguishing characteristic we can use, that's more efficient in runtime as a bonus. It's not clear to me from this snippet what object this script lives on, what objects it's iterating over, how they're instantiated, or what gameplay outcome this script is supporting. Can you edit your question to give us more of an overview of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have no idea about getting the instance of a prefab when the user drags the prefab into the scene view. The code shows my failure.

Comment: What do you mean "user drags the prefab into the scene view?" That's something that can only be done in the Editor. Are you creating a script to be used by other members of a development team?

Comment: I‘m creating a script for artists. They will drag prefab into the scene view and then the instances of prefabs are messy because all of them are roots of scene. I need to put all of instances under a parent node so that it will be easily managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found two solutions.

```
if (currentEvent.type == EventType.DragExited){
    var goes = Selection.gameObjects;
    for (int i = 0; i < goes.Length; i++){
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

```
if (currentEvent.type == EventType.DragExited){
    var objects = Object.FindObjectsOfType<MyScript>();//every prefab has MyScript component
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++){
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Then you can get the instances of prefabs that the user drags into the scene view.